# Is it possible to hide Windows' Cut, Copy, Delete, Rename buttons on the context menu when I am working on an checked-out directory?

Tags: tortoise-svn

I am using Tortoise client and get "paranoid" when I accidently delete/rename files or folders in a checked-out directory using Windows default Delete or Rename buttons as opposed to using Tortoise's that I should use.

*Is it possible to hide Windows' Cut, Copy, Delete, Rename buttons on the context menu when I am working ONLY on an checked-out directory?*

Comment: You do realize that Tortoise will mark these files in the commit dialog, and you can easily revert those with an `!` and remove those with a `?`?

Comment: If there's a distinction between a "normal folder" and the Tortoise one in the registry, sure.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is hard as the folder isn't different in the registry and thus the menu entries can't be easily changed.

However, what about moving those actions to the main centext menu in the TortoiseSVN settings?

[image]

<sub>There is a paste option at the bottom, I suppose it does the a rename action upon a cut item.</sub>